# Spring rest controller result wrapping with JsonView / MappingJacksonValue

Tags: json, spring, jackson, spring-web

I have a Spring API that allows the user to specify the JsonView of each call using a view param like so:

```
/api/v1/person/1?view=viewName
```

I then use Spring's MappingJacksonValue to set the correct view dynamically instead of using `@JsonView()` annotation and finally I just return the MappingJacksonValue instance which produces something along the lines of

```
[
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 }
]
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to easily wrap my MappingJacksonValue instances in an ObjectNode so that I can change all API results from the snippet above to this

```
{
    "data" : [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 }
    ]
}
```

I tried using a regular HashMap<> but that didn't work - the serialization completely ignores the MappingJacksonValue view and it also produces Map-specific results

```
{
    data: {
        value: [],
        serializationView: "com.blah.models.view.View$Id",
        filters: null,
        jsonpFunction: null
    }
}
```

So can someone pls let me know what's the best way to achieve result wrapping in my scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across this post looking to do the same thing, I realized I was looking at the problem in the wrong way. I ended up creating a ServiceResponse class and wrapped up the object in there like so

```
public class ServiceResponse {

    @JsonView(View.Id.class)
    private Object data;

    public ServiceResponse (Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

So essentially instead of returning `new MappingJacksonValue(someReturnObject)` I'm returning `new MappingJacksonValue(new ServiceResponse(someReturnObject))`. This way everything is wrapped nicely in a `data` JSON object and the `setSerializationView` method still filters my objects properly.

Hope this helps someone.